# Create new files in sequence when size exceeds 1 MB

Tags: python

My below code creates exception log files at location-

```
C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/
```

Initially code keeps writing into ExceptionLog_1.txt file whenever exception occurs and when the size of file exceeds 1 MB it starts writing to ExceptionLog_2.txt until its size is 1 MB. So far, it works perfect only for these 2 file creations and writing. When size of second file exceeds 1 MB it should log exceptions into a third log file ExceptionLog_3.txt. But, it does not works. Code keeps on writing into second file.

How to modify my code to make sure a new file is created when size of latest log file exceeds 1 MB?

```
def WriteExceptionToFile(self, traceback):

    count = 1
    fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/'
    # check if the path exists, create directory if not.
    if not (os.path.exists):
        os.mkdir(fileDir)

    filename = "ExceptionLog_"+ str(count) +".txt"
    filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, filename)

    try:
        if os.path.getsize(filepath) < 1048576: # if file size is less than 1 MB
            filename = "ExceptionLog_" + str(count) + ".txt"
        else:
            filename = "ExceptionLog_" + str(count + 1) + ".txt"        

    except OSError:
        Print("Path '%s' does not exists or is inaccessible" % filepath)
        filename = "ExceptionLog_1.txt"

    filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, filename)

    with open(filepath, 'a+') as f:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try an approach using rotating files from the `logging` module.

Example directly from the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

```
import glob
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_rotatingfile_example.out'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the log message handler to the logger, HERE YOU CAN SPECIFY THE FILE SIZE
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
              LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

# Log some messages
for i in range(20):
    my_logger.debug('i = %d' % i)

# See what files are created
logfiles = glob.glob('%s*' % LOG_FILENAME)

for filename in logfiles:
    print(filename)
```

Comment: For this particular case .. 
The handler will be set as following handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
              LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=1048576)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with using a class that way you wont have to worry about maintaining the correct count elsewhere.

Checkout the solution below

```
import os
class GenericExceptionWriter:
  def __init__(self):
    self.count = 1
    self.fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/'
    os.makedirs(self.fileDir, exist_ok=True)
    self.currentFilePath = "".join(["ExceptionLog_",str(self.count),".txt"])
    self.maxSize = 1048576

  def checkSize(self):
    if os.path.getsize(self.currentFilePath) > self.maxSize:
      self.count += 1
      self.currentFilePath = "".join(["ExceptionLog_",str(self.count),".txt"])

  def WriteExceptionToFile(self, traceback):
    try:
      self.checkSize()
    except OSError:
        print("Path '%s' does not exists or is inaccessible" % self.currentFilePath)
    filepath = os.path.join(self.fileDir, self.currentFilePath)

    with open(filepath, 'a+') as f:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)
        f.close()
```